# New to GO, error with assignment inside condition

Tags: go

I get an error with the code below that a and b assigned within the conditions are unused:

```
    package main

import "fmt"

//FizzBuzz n = 100
// Multiple of 3 output Fizz
//Multiple of 5 output Buzz
//Multiple of 3 and 5, FizzBuzz
func main(){
  for i:=0; i<=100; i++{
    a:= ""
    b:= ""
    if i%3 == 0 {
        a:="Fizz"
    }
    if i%5 == 0{
        b:="Buzz"
        
    }
    
        fmt.Println("number ",i,": ", a , b )

    }
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

`:=` creates a new variable in the current scope.

```
a := ""
b := ""
if i%3 == 0 {
    a := "Fizz"  // this creates a new "a", which shadows the outer "a" until the '}'
}
```

For assignment you want `=`.

```
a:= ""
b:= ""
if i%3 == 0 {
    a = "Fizz"  // the original "a" is re-assigned
}
```

(ditto for `b`)